# Is it true that everything in Python is an object, and that every object is implemented as a dictionary? Even built-in types?

Tags: python

The title of my question is really but an entrance to my real question here:

If even the attributes and methods making up an object are themselves objects too, and each one of those is actually a dictionary under-hood, then I can't help but think of an infinite chain of dictionaries having other dictionaries as values inside of them, since there is no, I believe, object in Python that has zero attributes and methods.

The only explanation I can think of is that built-in types and functions, which are the building blocks of all other objects and which are supposedly implemented as dictionaries too, have primitives and traditional C functions as ultimate values to end the chain. But that's only a speculation.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Dictionaries themselves are implemented in C.

Comment: Python objects are not dictionaries but most of them have a dictionary for dynamic attributes.

Comment: @Dan D: I read in Learn Python Programming, 2nd ed about the dictionary data type, that "it is the backbone of every Python object.". Maybe it meant something else.. I'm not really sure